# Regex, match two sequences in one sentence

Tags: java, regex

Say there is a sentence

> That Sam-I-am

Two words end in the same sequence "am", where the second sequence is the last word.

I need to write a regular expression to match such a sentence, where the sequence could be any string of letters.

The language is Java. What I don't quite understand is how one would match something within a sentence and ignore the rest.

It is a prep question for a Java test.

Thank you.

This is code I'm using to test

```
public static void doMatching(){

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    try {

        String pattern, s;
        System.out.print("Pattern: ");
        pattern = in.readLine();
        while (!pattern.equals("quit")){
            System.out.print("String: ");
            s = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(Pattern.matches(pattern, s));
            System.out.print("Pattern: ");
            pattern = in.readLine();
        }
        } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error!");
    } catch (Exception e2){
        System.out.println("Unknown!");
    }

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    doMatching();
}
```

And here is the result

```
Pattern: (\\w+\\b).*\\b\\1$
String: that sam-i-am
false
```

Comment: So you need a regular expression to see if any word ends with the last word?

Comment: What have you tried, what language are you doing this in, and what do you intend to do with this information?  All three of these questions alter the answer.

Comment: I'm using Java. I cannot wrap my head around how I would create a generic sequence. I could match [am]{2}, but do not know how I would match with in a sentence and ignore all other. It is a prep question for a test.

Comment: Okay, you've answered one of my four questions.  What about the others?

Comment: I apologize, the "enter" to submit always gets me.

Comment: Okay, you just need to confirm or deny that the last word is used to end a word earlier in the string?

Comment: yes! Exactly. Or could have occurred by itself earlier as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"(\\w+\\b).*\\b\\1$"
```

That will match some non-trivial number of word characters at the end of a word`(\\w+\\b)` and ensure that they match at the end of the string as a complete word.

Comment: +1, but note that "word character" is not actually the same as "letter".

Comment: @ruakh, that's fair.  isal, you should watch out for these specifics.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to understand the expression. But a quick trial showed it not working.

Comment: You should post the code you're using, because this is the correct regular expression.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan, +1 for being faster than me. ;O

Comment: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?32pv5  <-- Works here, isal.  OmnipotentEntity gave a great explanation.

Comment: @isal Don't escape when you're entering the pattern.  The way I wrote it is for direct entry as a string.  `(\w+\b).*\b\1$` should be what you enter on the command line.

Comment: I do see that it is working. Thank you :). I will try and adapt it to my program.

Comment: If you're writing it into a program, a much (much) faster solution would be to reverse the string and use `^(\w+)\b.*?\b\1` - essentially, you're checking that the word at the beginning of the string is used to start a word later in the string.  It's faster because of the lazy quantification.

Comment: I found out why it isn't working. Given a sentence, I have to say if such a property exists. The code, matches only the () part of the string - "This s(am-i-am)". How do I match the entire sentence and hence, is true.

Comment: All you have to say is 'I found a match, this is true'

Answer (score 2):

The regex you're searching for is:

```
(\w+\b).*\b\1$
```

This also includes an underscore as a letter, if you need to exclude that you can use `[a-zA-Z]`

`\w` matches any letter
`+` matches the previous expression 1 or more times, in a greedy fashion
`\b` matches a word boundary.  It's a zero-width match.
`()` groups and saves the result so you can use it later as a backreference
`.` matches anything except a newline
`*` matches the previous expression 0 or more times, in a greedy fashion
`\1` is the first backreference, it matches the first thing captured by `()`
`$` is a zero-width match on the end of the string.

A zero-width match is a match that doesn't actually include any characters.

Comment: This is wrong.  All this enforces is that the end of the string is repeated at some point earlier.  Use word boundaries to avoid this issue.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I missed the word boundary requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There are other good answers here, but I think this is more appropriate still:

```
([a-zA-Z]+)\b.+\b\1$
```

Perhaps splitting hairs, but with RegEx it's a good idea to be as concise and as deliberate as possible.

The character ranges here seem better than `\w` because of the nature of the question.  I think it's better to move the first word boundary outside of the capturing group.  And `.+` vs. `.*` because there *must* be at least one non-word character present (although `.*` combined with the word boundaries will almost certainly match as well).

Comment: `I think it's better to move the first boundary outside of the capturing group.` Style choice?  I guess it is kind of pointless to have a zero-width match in a capture group.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity Yeah, I agree that it's not critical. It's more about being deliberate and explicit. In my experience that simply makes the code easier to support down the road.